Power Query M formula: Get data from sheet in same file with Csv.Document()
I want to use the Power Query M function Csv.Document() to get data from a named sheet within the same file. How would I do this?
This is how I can get the data from another file on the disc:
= Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\foo\OneDrive\Desktop\test.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=1, Encoding=65001])

But I prefer to paste the CSV content into a sheet in the same file, and then use Power Query to get its data to put it into the Data Model. The reason is the file is shared over OneDrive, so any paths will not be the same for different users opening the file.
In effect I want to replace File.Contents("C:\Users\foo\OneDrive\Desktop\test.csv") with a function to get the data from a sheet in the same file.
Example of CSV content I want to paste in a sheet (updated to proper format):
"created","currency","gross","fee","net","reporting_category","customer_facing_amount","customer_facing_currency","shipping_address_country","payment_metadata[order_id]"
"2024-01-01 23:56:03","sek","4262.52","65.74","4196.78","charge","390.83","eur","ES","2955"
"2024-01-02 12:49:26","sek","926.66","24.97","901.69","charge","85.00","eur","GB","2958"


With Excel.CurrentWorkbook() you can return named ranges or tables, so maybe after you paste the csv, you could Name the range or turn it into a table.

@RonRosenfeld I have tried something along those lines, but did not get it to work. Could you supply the complete formula as an example?

Just use the Data From=>Table option and change the Name="some name" to whatever your named range or table really is. Assuming when you pasted the data occupies multiple rows, you won't be able to use the Csv.Document function. You'll have to split the lines using the Table.SplitColumn function.

@RonRosenfeld can you supply a complete formula as an example, that works?

Do what I suggested, then look at the Advanced Editor in Power Query for the code.

@RonRosenfeld I am sorry, I tried but failed. If you supply an answer to this question with the formula, and explaining the different parts, I can mark this as answered. I would not have asked if I knew what to do.

Edit your question to provide in markdown format a data sample of what you might be pasting into your Excel sheet.

That is a strange CSV document. Each line is completely enclosed in double quotes which means each line would not normally be split at all. How do you expect it to be split?

Given that there seem to be extra double-quotes in your pasted document, I think the following will process it.
After you paste the text into a worksheet, you could use the Data=>From Table/Range and then replace the code in the advanced editor with the code below.
Might have to make some changes if your documents are not all in similar formats.
As Pasted

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],

//May or may not need this step depending on how you set up your table
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),

//Remove leading double quote and replace doubled double quotes with a single quote
    #"Remove extra quotes" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Demoted Headers",
        each [Column1],
        null,
        (x,y,z)=> Text.TrimStart(Text.Replace(y,"""""",""""),""""),
        {"Column1"}),

    doc = Csv.Document(Text.Combine(#"Remove extra quotes"[Column1],"#(lf)")),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(doc, [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"

Processed


The columns are arbitrary in each doc. That solution seems to require me to write the actual column headers, which means it does not scale to any CSV document?
I would have thought it should be possible to use this:

Just that the File.Contents() part would be replaced with the content from a sheet?

@user1853417 I've edited my post show how you can use Csv.Document to return the same thing. However, as I wrote in my answer, you cannot use that function directly on what you paste because what you are pasting is not a valid Csv document. The result is the same, in any event. But you'll also need a routine to properly set the data types dynamically, depending on the column contents. This can be done in PQ if your data is such that the first row will always be data of the correct type.

I updated my original post to proper CSV, and with more exact info on what I needed done. Can you update your answer accordingly? Thanks @RonRosenfeld.

@user1853417 Please include in your update: how you pasted the data into Excel; the structure of the resulting table; the M-Code you tried in your attempt to adapt my suggestion to your problem; and where you ran into trouble. The details are important in crafting a solution as the basic line to create the csv document from your data doc = Csv.Document(Text.Combine(#"Previous Step"[Column1],"#(lf)")) does not change and should work.
